# Is it service or entrypoint who should transform request data into domain model

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a simple microservice build with go-kit and protocol buffers. And I have a question about where should I transform request into business-ish data.

For instance, I have following protobuf

```
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

service Location {
  rpc DeleteLocation(DeleteLocationRequest) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {};
}

message DeleteLocationRequest {
  string locationUID = 1;
}
```

A request has uid to delete as a string; however, I would like to use my custom struct

```
type LocationUID struct {
    uuid.UUID
}
```

So, I'm wondering where it's better to transform incoming string into domain object.

**Should I do it inside entrypoint?** Get data from reqeust, transform it into LocationUID and then call service with business logic to perform a required action.

**Or is it better to place inside service?** Pass the whole request object from entrypoint into a service and then, inside service, get reqired data, transform it, validate (and return an error if data is invalid)

Comment: Perhaps a bad example, however Spring can do it directly at the entrypoint level, plus I imagine that you might want to catch any wrong input as soon as possible (thus in the entrypoint) rather than having to go into the service and go back up the stack again in such a case.